# Do I need a Segger J-Link to program the Invensense FireFly shield?

Tags: sensors

I'm about to go out and purchase the [Invensense FireFly](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/firefly-development-kit/) eval kit so we can begin evaluation and research into the SensorStudio Platform for gesture recognition.

I'm not exactly clear on what the Segger J-Link Debugger will be used for.
Do we absolutely need the J-Link to PROGRAM from sensorstudio to the firefly board or can it also go through the Arduino sketch as a header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segger J-Link is required to debug your custom sensor (your application/algo) on the embedded system (Cortex M0 in the InvenSense FireFly 6axis) with InvenSense SensorStudio.  If you do not purchase the Segger J-Link you cannot effectively design/develop your application which will more likely than not require "on target" debug of the embedded system, which contains your custom application.  Segger J-Link is not used to flash code to the InvenSense FireFly.  Segger J-Link is therefore used for debug only.

Comment: So does SensorStudio generate a header file with precompiled binary that is loaded at runtime into the Firefly's on board processors?